# Can every anti-derivative be expressed as an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

This is a question for my homework. I'm quite confused with it. I understand the question as choosing an anti-derivative which cannot be expressed as an integral.
So how is the limit related to the question? How can I use the hint?

Comment: The limit tells you *some* "anti-derivative which cannot be expressed as an integral." Basically, in (1), consider $F(x) = \lim_{A\to-\infty} \int_ {A}^x f(t)dt$. (If we were in the second case of the "or", the first is similar). What can you say about $F$, now?

Comment: (Note: I think for the result claimed in 1. to hold, you actually need $f>0$ (not just $f\geq 0$), since for instance $f$ could otherwise just be identically 0 on some $(\infty,a]$)

Comment: @ClementC., did you mean $(-\infty a]$ instead of $(\infty,a]$?

Comment: Yea, indeed, that was a typo @BarryCipra

Comment: I understood part $a$ but I still have doubts about part $b$. We have $$\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_0^a f(t)dt+ \int_a^x f(t)dt.$$ If $x \rightarrow \infty$, the left side tends to $\infty$. The third integral is a constant and we conclude that $\int_a^x f(t)dt$ tends to $\infty$, but I don't know how to conclude part $b$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Take, for instance, $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$. Then for any $a\in\mathbb R$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt<\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\pi$. So, the function $F(x)=\arctan(x)+10$, which is a primitive of $f$, cannot be expressed as$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$

Comment: That's true, but that does not fully help the OP to figure out the exercise they are trying to solve. You solve the overall question, but miss part of the actual question (i.e., you go too fast).

Comment: An even simpler counterexample would be $f(x)=0$, $F(x)=1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Sure!

Answer (score 1):

For part a, f you have any antiderivative $F(x)$, then $F(x)+C$ is also an anti-derivative for any real number $C$.  Suppose the first limit is $N$ and let

$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \; dt.$$

Then for any $a$, you have

$$\int_a^x f(t) \; dt = F(x) - F(a).$$

So if this were to represent all anti-derivatives, then $F(a)$ would have to represent all values of $C$.  But it can't because at least one of those limits exists.

For part b, if both of those limits are $+\infty$ then the second limit can be written

$$\lim_{A\to -\infty} -\int_0^A f(t) \; dt = -\infty.$$

So in this case $F(a)$ takes on all real values $C$.

Comment: I understood part a, but I didn't understand part b. Can you help me? Is there a typo and the value of the integral is $\infty$ instead of $-\infty$?